# Обновление критериев в LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates()

Tags: android, gps

Доброго времени суток, уважаемое сообщество.
Пишу приложения для определения гео-координат в фоновом режиме(Service):

```
public class GeoService extends Service implements LocationListener {
    LocationManager lm;
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}
public void onCreate() {
   lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
       lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                60000, 0, this); // пытаемся получить данные каждые 60 секунд

}

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
// получили требуемые данные:
double latitude = location.getLatitude();
double longitude = location.getLongitude();

if(need_refresh){ //разовое событие, сигнализирущее об обновлении параметров    
    lm.removeUpdates(this);
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
            120000,0, this);}       
}

public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

В момент срабатывания **`if(need_refresh)`** данные начинают обновляться постоянно, вопреки установленным новым параметрам. Прошу совета - как грамотно реализовать изменение параметров в `LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В итоге опытным путем выяснилось, что **не стоит устанавливать метраж перемещения равным нулю**

```
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
        120000,10, this);}
```

Answer (score 1):

Подозреваю, что вместо `onCreate()` в сервисе вам нужно использовать `onStartCommand()` - это первое что заметил.

И как-то странная логика: меняется местоположение - вы удаляете обработчик и ставите новый с другим провайдером. Здесь тоже думаю стоит поменять логику.

Может поможет - [Good way of getting the user's location in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181704/good-way-of-getting-the-users-location-in-android).

[Understanding the LocationListener in Android](http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2010/12/25/understanding-locationlistener-android/).